# How to select a specific part in a .csv file on multiple lines? (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, sum

I'm making this example up for the sake of explaining the problem.
If I have a .csv file as follows:

```
alfa, bravo, Charlie, 1.31
Dragonball, manga, anime, 3.11
delta, Omega, cookie, 3.13
Dragonball, stan, lee, 1.13
```

How can I pick up the fourth part of each line which has "Dragonball" as the first part? If the list goes on further, and I do not know which lines have the "Dragonball" as the first part.

I have tried:

```
list = []
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    part = line.split(",")
    if part[0] == Dragonball:
        list.append(part[3])
```

Expected output:

```
list = [3.11, 1.13]
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html? Selecting items by index from a list is one of the most basic things to do in Python.

Comment: Also, if you are going to ask, please properly include the expected output instead of only vaguely explaining it with words

Comment: Hey folks. I'll rephrase my question in just a bit, it may be a little unclear. My goal is not to select these two parts, but to find a solution on selecting parts according to words used on the line in which the parts are.

Comment: Your code should work just fine if you change `Dragonball` to `"Dragonball"` (a string).

Comment: Hi, mkrieger1, thanks for the tip. Nice to hear I wasn't completely wrong in my approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path to your csv file")

print(list(df[df[0]=='Dragonball'][3]))
```

Output:

```
[3.11, 1.13]
```

Comment: Works. Thank you for your time!